# Return type of generic Map.entrySet()

Tags: java, generics

Map.entrySet() is declared as:

```
Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();
```

Somewhere I define a variable like this:

```
Map<? extends Number, String> wildCardMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now, I assume that the type param K is **? extends Number** and I could do this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>> entries = wildCardMap.entrySet();
```

But this gives a compilation error, and I have to write:

```
Set<? extends Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>> entries = wildCardMap.entrySet();
```

Can someone explain why the wildcard is necessary right before Map.Entry?

Comment: Dupe of producer extends? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super (I didn't flag.)

Comment: The problem is that the first and second `? extends Number` don't refer to the same `?`.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard `? extends Number` means some specific (unknown to us) type that extends `Number`. So let's try one possible type it could be, `Integer`, and see what happens:

```
Map<Integer, String> wildCardMap;

// doesn't compile
Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>> entries = wildCardMap.entrySet();
```

Why? Because `wildCardMap.entrySet()` returns `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>`, which is not a subtype of `Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>>`.

Generics are invariant and type arguments must match exactly, unless the type argument is a wildcard. A wildcard at a deeper level doesn't count (it's just part of the type). `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>` is not a subtype of `Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>>`, even though `Map.Entry<Integer, String>` is a subtype of `Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>`, just like how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: This doesn't explain what's the problem with this line:
   `Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>> entries = wildCardMap.entrySet();`

For example this is really similar code, and yet works:
`Set<List<? extends Number>> one = new HashSet<>();
Set<List<? extends Number>> two = one;`

Comment: @jakk: As I said, in my example, `wildCardMap.entrySet()` returns `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>`, which is not assignable to `Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>>`. So in other words, `Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> one; Set<Map.Entry<? extends Number, String>> two = one;`, which doesn't work. Neither does `Set<List<Integer>> one; Set<List<? extends Number>> two = one;`